# How can I make the phone automatically disable mobile connection when calling?

Tags: calls, 3g, htc-incredible-s

I recently moved from 2G network to 3G.

On 2G when I call somebody - the phone automatically suspends the mobile Internet (since it cannot send data and voice at the same time) and activates back when the call ends.

Now on 3G I just cannot call when the mobile Internet is active (no matter whether it downloads something or not) - the call is reset immediately. At the same time I can receive calls, i.e. if somebody calls me - the phone rings and I can talk.

If I disable the mobile Internet and use WiFi (or do not use any connection) - it works fine.

Changing the network type (auto, 3G, etc...) doesn't help.

Android 2.3.3. Go Launcher + Go Contacts Ex.

Two questions:

1. Is this an issue with the phone?
2. Is there something I can tune inside the phone to make it auto-switch the mobile Internet like it was on 2G (maybe 3rd party application or patch/fix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to talk to your carrier about your phone or service because data is separate from  voice (if you are not on a CDMA network). Voice is using GSM/UMTS and data is HSPA. Your data network usage should never interrupt your voice call, even if you use CDMA. The voice should take priority and stop the data usage to make the call. There is either an issue with the network you are on, or the phone.